# How to install hadoop user environment (HUE) in Raspberry Pi-3?

Tags: hadoop

When hue install on **Raspberry pi** ,get error .

```
/usr/local/hue-4.1.0/Makefile.sdk:120: recipe for target '/usr/local/hue- 
4.1.0/desktop/core/build/cryptography-1.3.1/egg.stamp' failed
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/hue-4.1.0/desktop/core/build/cryptography- 
1.3.1/egg.stamp] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/hue-4.1.0/desktop/core'
Makefile:70: recipe for target '.recursive-env-install/core' failed

make[1]: *** [.recursive-env-install/core] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/hue-4.1.0/desktop'

Makefile:73: recipe for target 'desktop' failed
make: *** [desktop] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Jessie as the new openssl libs in Stretch cause compile problems with Hadoop, so specifically this release:

http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2017-07-05/

You'll need to install the build dependencies, I use these (but they do include all the ones need for hadoop compilation too, so you could slim it down quite a bit)

```
apt-get install oracle-java8-jdk maven build-essential autoconf automake libtool cmake zlib1g-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libfuse-dev libsnappy-dev libsnappy-java libbz2-dev python-dev libsasl2-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libkrb5-dev libffi-dev libldap2-dev libmysqlclient-dev libsqlite3-dev libgmp3-dev libssl-dev
```

Then download, unpack and build hue 3.11.0

```
wget http://gethue.com/downloads/releases/3.11.0/hue-3.11.0.tgz
tar -zxvf hue-3.11.0.tgz
cd hue-3.11.0
make apps
```

I've tested this with 3.11, 3.12, 4.1 and 4.2 using the same build environment on the Pi-3.

If you are looking to build a full hadoop environment on the pi you might want to look at hadoopi:

https://github.com/andyburgin/hadoopi

The README has all the instructions on building and configuring a bunch of hadoop components in addition to Hue.

Andy